# Equivalent to viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear() in android SDK?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I am new to objective C. I would like to know what are similar methods to viewWillAppear() and viewDidAppear() in android. I guess viewDidAppear() is same as onResume() in android. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i want equivalent to viewWillAppear() not viewDidLoad().

Comment: That question appears to be exactly like yours and has an accepted answer.

Comment: yes it appears to be same. I even specified viewDidAppear() may be same as onResume() in android. But I could not find android equivalent to viewWillAppear() thats why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be activity lifecycle can help here goes the link [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

Comment: I know android's activity lifecycle. I am supposed to convert an iOS app into android and I am not understanding what can be possible equivalent for viewWillAppear() :(

Comment: onStart is equivalent to viewWillAppear check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart())

Comment: yes it is onStart(). Thanks :)